# monitoring for changes in file(s) in real time

Tags: r, monitoring, real-time

I have a program that monitors certain files for change. As soon as the file gets updated, the file is processed. So far I've come up with this general approach of handing "real time analysis" in R. I was hoping you guys have other approaches. Maybe we can discuss their advantages/disadvantages.

```
monitor <- TRUE
start.state <- file.info$mtime # modification time of the file when initiating

while(monitor) {
  change.state <- file.info$mtime
  if(start.state < change.state) {
    #process
  } else {
    print("Nothing new.")
  }
  Sys.sleep(sleep.time)
}
```

Comment: In general, this might be fine, but it will hog the R event loop until you kill the while loop. It won't be running in the background, for example, allowing you to get on with work. Which is fine if you can leave the process running, but I like the cron job RScript answer supplied below.

Comment: Can you not put a call to run the R script in whatever is updating the file?

Comment: @James, that may be doable, but I will have to check.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: `?utils::changedFiles`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to the suggestion to use a system API, this can be also done using [qtbase](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=454) which will be a cross-platform means from within R:

```
dir_to_watch <- "/tmp"

library(qtbase)
fsw <- Qt$QFileSystemWatcher()
fsw$addPath(dir_to_watch)

id <- qconnect(fsw, "directoryChanged", function(path) {
  message(sprintf("directory %s has changed", path))
})

cat("abc", file="/tmp/deleteme.txt")
```

Comment: downvoted since the package is no longer being maintained, so this response is of limited current value, when it may have been useful at one point in time.

Answer (score 7):

I have a hack in mind: you can setup a CRON job/Scheduled task to run R script every *n* seconds (or whatever). R script checks the file hash, and if hashes don't match, runs the analysis. You can use `digest::digest` function, just check out the manual.

Comment: aL3xa - Can you expound on this flow in some greater detail / sources for where you got this idea?  I think this would better fit with my process, but hard to know what you mean by using the digest package

Answer (score 6):

If your system provides an API for monitoring filesystem changes, then you should use that. I believe Macs come with this. Not sure about other platforms though.

Edit:
A quick goog gave me:

Linux - http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/FAM

Win32 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx

Obviously, these APIs will eliminate any polling that you require. On the other hand, they may not always be available.

Java has this: http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/ and http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#6

Comment: On Linux, `gamin` and `inotify` can do the trick. http://www.noah.org/wiki/FAM,_Gamin,_inotify

Comment: These seem newer and better supported. Thanks aL3xa.

Comment: `git status --porcelain` also checks hashes to see which files have been changed, with output in a form that is parseable by scripts.  You'd need to set up the files so that they were tracked by git though.

Answer (score 3):

If you have lots of files that you want to monitor, then R may be too slow for this purpose.  Go to your `c:` or `/` dir and see how long it takes to do `file.info(dir(recursive = TRUE))`.  A dos or bash script may be quicker.

Otherwise, the code looks fine.

Comment: I always have R in mind, that's the problem... =) Bash script can check the file hash and run R script if needed. That's definitely a better solution.

Comment: I will be monitoring only a couple of files.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the tclTaskSchedule function in the tcltk2 package to set up a function that checks for updates and runs your code.  This would then be run on a regular basis (you set the timing) but would still allow you to use your R session.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer another solution for windows that I have been using in a production environment that works perfectly and that I find very easy to set up and, under the hood it basically accesses the system API for monitoring folder changes as others have mentioned, but all the "hard work" is taken care of for you.  I use a freely available piece of software called Folder Monitor by [Nodesoft](https://www.nodesoft.com/foldermonitor) and well described [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/08/07/monitor-folders-on-windows-with-folder-monitor/#:%7E:text=Folder%20Monitor%20is%20a%20free,commands%20if%20that%20is%20desired.).  Once you execute this program, it appears in your system tray and from there you can specify a given directory to monitor.  When files are written to the directory (or changed or modified - there are a few options from which you can choose), the program executes any program you like.  I simply link the program to a windows batch that that calls my R Script.  So for example, I have Folder Monitor set up to monitor a "\myservername\DropOff" UNC path for any new data files written to it.  When Folder Monitor detects new files, it executes RunBatch.bat file that simply runs an R script (see [here](https://www.statmethods.net/interface/batch.html) for information on setting that up) that validates the format of the expected file based on an expected naming convention for files received and then it unzips and processes the data, creating a dataframe and ultimately loads that into a SQL Server Database.  It just doesn't get any easier.

One note if you decide to use this solution:  take a look at the optional delay execution parameter, which might be important if files take a while to copy into the target directory from the source location.