# Acting on changes to a log file in R as they happen

Tags: r, io

Suppose a log file is being written to disk with one extra line appended to it every so often (by a process I have no control over).

I would like to know a clean way to have an R program "watch" the log file, and process a new line when it is written to the log file.

Any advice would by much appreciated.

Comment: In this post there are some suggests and solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780632/monitoring-for-changes-in-files-in-real-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file.info` to get the modification date of a file, just check every so often and take action is the modification date changes. Keeping track of how many lines have already been read will enable you to use `scan` or `read.table` to read only the new lines.

You could also delete or move the log file after it is read by your program. The external program will then create a new log file, I assume. Using `file.exists` you can check if the file has been recreated, and read it when needed. You then add the new data to the already existing data.

I would move the log file to an `archive` subfolder and read the logfiles as they are created.