# Constantly scanning for new files in R working directory

Tags: r, automation, conditional-statements, read.csv

Is there a way to make R continuously scan the working directory for new files (in this case, CSVs), and whenever it finds a new file has been added to the working directory, to read it and perform some (always the same) task on it, and then go back to scanning for new files, until I tell it to stop?

Comment: Set up a cron job, that would run the same script in regular intervals, or use infinite loop like:  `while(TRUE){ list.files()... check if any new, if yes, then tasks}` you might want to introduce pause within while loop.

Comment: You can make use of this: https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR

Comment: Very similar question: answers suggest using a system API or the qtbase package.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780632/monitoring-for-changes-in-files-in-real-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend putting this in a while loop.

```
setwd("path_you're_interested_in")
old_files <- character(0)
while(TRUE){
   new_files <- setdiff(list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$"), old_files)
   sapply(new_files, function(x) {
       # do stuff
   })
   old_files = c(old_files, new_files)
   Sys.sleep(30) # wait half minute before trying again
}
```

Comment: I made some pretty heavy edits - the loop will now only look for files with new names, you don't need a data table dependency when we don't know what OP wants to do, `//` doesn't work for comments in R, and I added in a pause.

Comment: @Gregor good points. thanks for the help

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!