# R file Watcher to always read in files

Tags: r, file-watcher

I am having an issue creating a R file watcher that can watch a directory for the presence of files constantly. There has to be a better way to do this but my searches have not yielded results. fundamentally, this works, but since the loop does not break, the data frames are never accessible in the console.

```
 while(watch_file == TRUE){
  setwd("C:/Users/315010322/Desktop/mike/")
  File_List <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
  File_List_Clean <- str_extract(File_List, '.*(?=\\.csv)')
      for(i in 1:length(File_List)){
        df <- read.csv(File_List[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        assign(File_List_Clean[i], df)
      }
  Sys.sleep(60)
}
```

Comment: The main R loop isn't practically multi-threaded. You can't really have asynchronous code just and update your session periodically. That can get very confusing if you are using data while it gets updated.

Comment: You can possibly use a package that introduces an alternate event loop. For example see there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780632/monitoring-for-changes-in-files-in-real-time

Comment: @MrFlick there is going to be more to this loop. This is basically going to turn into an ETL process, so once the file is read in, the file will be moved either to an error or processed folder. I would have written this is in but it would not have solved my problem. That said, should I look into a multi threading and handle it that way knowing that once the files are read in, they will disappear?

Comment: @MrFlick I tried to install the package but it is apparently not available for R version 3.5.0. I was hoping I would not have to downgrade.

Comment: So you don't need the data.frames accessible in the console? Then this solution should be fine. Otherwise you're basically going to have to set up sort of server-like process. Perhaps the [firey](https://github.com/thomasp85/fiery) package might be of interest. But really R might not be the best language for this (at least the file watching part).

Comment: @MrFlick alright thanks a lot for the help! I guess I'll move the work over to python. Or i guess I can wrap the R scripts in python.